# Cannot read property 'xyz' of undefined in Google Apps Script...even when variable is clearly defined

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script

```
function doPost(e){
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const pr = JSON.stringify(e);
  var a1 = pr.parameters.aoutlet;
  AddRecord(a1);
}

// pr
//{"parameters":{"Bill-Amt":[""],"Vendor0":["ko"],"aoutlet":["GM"],"Vendor":["555"].....
```

And it Apps Script says...
Cannot read property 'aoutlet' of undefined (line 13, file "Code")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
function doPost(e){
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const pr = JSON.stringify(e);
  var a1 = pr.parameters.aoutlet;
  AddRecord(a1);
}
```

#### To:

```
function doPost(e){
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var a1 = e.parameters[0].aoutlet;
  AddRecord(a1);

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok");
}
```

or

```
function doPost(e){
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var a1 = e.parameter.aoutlet;
  AddRecord(a1);

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok");
}
```

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

Comment: It says - Cannot read property '0' of undefined... but I know pr definitely has data

Comment: @Arshiva Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `It says - Cannot read property '0' of undefined... but I know pr definitely has data`, I'm worried that whether you have reflected your modified script to your Web Apps after you modified your script by my proposed modification. Because when I tested your script by reflecting on my proposed script, such an error doesn't occur. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Thankyou for quick reply. After making the change I saved it as new deployment. And I also did a test deployment. Sadly the result was same.... It's just simple JSON thing but I'm failing to understand why it shows as undefined. In the end I know it'be a stupid error.

Comment: @Arshiva Thank you for replying. Now, I thought that I might notice your current issue. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize again. By the way, in this case, it supposes that your `AddRecord` works. Please be careful this.

Comment: @Arshiva Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor skill. I lately noticed the actual issue. But, I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

You're using [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) on the `e` object, so `pr` is a string.

You are then trying to access properties in that string as if it was an object, and this is causing your error.

#### Solution:

Don't use `JSON.stringify`. Use `e` instead:

```
var a1 = e.parameters.aoutlet;
```